# jQuery AutoComplete in .net MVC 3 to Update Target Element as user types

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQueryUI autocomplete on a search box. All works fine. However, I wanted the result table to be updated instead of the dropdown list of jQuery suggestion list. Something like Google Search... as you type the result changes. Is there any example of that?

Comment: @Shauib: Any reason in particular you need to use the autocomplete widget for this? Why not create your own system that updates a `div` with the results of an ajax call (or local data source) fired on keydown in the text

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the reply. I thought it would be easier since it is doing most of the stuff I need. Just needed the result to be displayed differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either customize the plugin or use http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AutocompleteTableLayout
This plugin is still in beta, the author just extended the original autocomplete plugin to use a table layout instead of the dropdown list